# codeigniter render html to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, mpdf

I have a page that needs to be printed to a 'A4' content. So I've tried to use the mPDF library. In that page, I have a calendar content. At first I used CI's Calendar, and when I rendered it to mPDF it works perfectly. But I recently changed the calendar to a jquery calendar due to user's specification. So I changed it using [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).
When I passed it to mPDF, it displayed my other content in that page, but the javascript for the FullCalendar didn't appear in the PDF.

I was thinking to change my output to an image. Is there any tools (meaning libraries) to change my output to image and display it in the browser?

Note : There is **javascript** and **css** in my page, which I've read that most pdf generating tools can't render either javascript or css, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using canvas to create an image of the screen and then sending it to your PDF creator.  I realize this isn't a full fledged answer, but it's something I'm looking into for a similar purpose.  [This question has some more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots).

Comment: This is good, thank you. But the documentation and usage guide needs some work because I still don't know how to use it